# Using MonkeyTalk to test android app, the record button stays disabled

Tags: automated-testing, android, eclipse, monkeytalk

I am unable to record in [MonkeyTalk](https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk), the record button stays disabled

I took the following steps:

1. Created a sample android project in eclipse
2. Created libs folder in the android project and copied monkey talk agent into the libs folder(monkeytalk-agent-2.1.10.jar)
3. Right-click on project and configured to Configure -> Convert to AspectJ Project
4. Right-click on project and select AspectJ Tools -> Add to AspectJpath
5. Opened the AndroidManifest.xml and copied the below two lines in that XML file to give permission
6. Right-click on the android project and navigated to project properties-> Java Build Path-> Order and Export tab -> checked AspectJ Runtime Library.
7. Right-click on project ->Run ->Android application.
8. After that, I created a sample project in MonkeyTalkIDEProfessional
9. And then I created a sample test script in the project(Right-click on project and navigated to New -> Script).
10. Clicked on android connection icon and selected the option(Android Emulator) option. In this case, the record button of MonkeyTalkIDEProfessional is disabled.

How do I get the record button enabled?

Comment: And your question is? What is your goal and what is not working as expected?

Comment: Hi, sorry for hassle,i am unable to record monkeytalk, the record button is disable.

Comment: Updated your question a bit. I don't think a lot of folks here are experienced with MonkeyTalk. I would also ask on their forums: https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/forum or contact support https://www.cloudmonkeymobile.com/monkeytalk/support . If you do find an answer please add it here as well. Goodluck :)

Comment: I've already answered the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29621397/using-monkeytalk-to-test-android-app-the-record-button-is-disabled